# Global Snackbar Handling Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar

Seeing as I have multiple places where snackbars could be triggered, I want to have a central place in my app where I can handle showing/dismissing snackbars.

This is the structure of my app:

[image: app structure]

I've implemented a BaseViewModel that contains a StateFlow which should keep track of the SnackBar message (every other ViewModel inherits from this BaseViewModel):

```
@HiltViewModel
open class BaseViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    val _snackBarMessage = MutableStateFlow("")
    val snackBarMessage: StateFlow<String> = _snackBarMessage
}
```

To test if the update of the StateFlow is triggered correctly, I've implemented a message that should update the StateFlow after every login:

```
private fun setSnackBarMessage() {
   _snackBarMessage.value = "A wild snackBar appeared"
}
```

MainContent contains my Scaffold (incl. scaffoldState, snackbarHost), should react to changes in the snackBarMessage flow and display/dismiss the Snackbar when needed:

```
fun MainContent(...){
   val message by viewModel.snackBarMessage.collectAsState()

   LaunchedEffect(message) {
      if (message.isNotEmpty() Timber.d("We got a snackbar")
   }

   Scaffold(...){...}
}
```

During debugging, I noticed that after every login the snackBarMessage value is updated correctly but MainContent does not get those updates which, in turn, means that the snackbar is never displayed.

Is there a reason why MainContent does not get those updates from the LoginComposable?
Is it even possible to have a central instance of a snackbar or do I really need to handle snackbars separately in every Composable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use this

@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val showSnackBar: (
        message: String?,
        actionLabel: String,
        actionPerformed: () -> Unit,
        dismissed: () -> Unit
    ) -> Unit = { message, actionLabel, actionPerformed, dismissed ->
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val snackBarResult = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = message.toString(),
                actionLabel = actionLabel
            )
            when (snackBarResult) {
                SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed -> actionPerformed.invoke()
                SnackbarResult.Dismissed -> dismissed.invoke()
            }
        }
    }


    //Global using
    showSnackBar.invoke(
        "YOUR_MESSAGE",
        "ACTION_LABEL",
        {
         //TODO ON ACTION PERFORMED
        },
        {
         //TODO ON DISMISSED
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the cause of your problem is using message as the key for `LaunchedEffect` and not changing the message at the same time. In the documentation you can read that type of side-effect will be re-launched after key modification.

> If LaunchedEffect is recomposed with different keys (see the
> Restarting Effects section below), the existing coroutine will be
> cancelled and the new suspend function will be launched in a new
> coroutine.
>
> Some effects in Compose, like LaunchedEffect, produceState, or
> DisposableEffect, take a variable number of arguments, keys, that are
> used to cancel the running effect and start a new one with the new
> keys.

I suggest wrapping snackbar message in some kind of object (not data class) with field containing snackbar content.

Cheers

Comment: But message is never changed (always ""). I've also tried using ```LaunchedEffect(Unit)``` but still no change.

Comment: Unit is an object and constant as well. Have you tried with message which changes ?

Comment: Yes, I have. My problem is that any changes from message are not observed in MainContent, when message is changed in another Composable (f.ex. Login)

Comment: In that case you are using a  few  instances of BaseVM instead of one. Make sure that viewModel used by MainContent is the only instance interacted by `setSnackBarMessage`. You cannot invoke this method on other viemModels and expect snackbar because each viewmodel has another instance of stateflow